# centOS 7: segmentation fault (core dumped) when type java -version

Tags: java, java-8, centos7

I have been fighting this problem for quite a long but could not get a solution. Had searched net but could not find anything concrete.

I have removed all openJDK1.8.0_xx from my system using `yum remove java*`. 
Then I have installed Oracle Java i.e. jdk1.8.0_151 using standard methods i.e.

1. Download the .tar.gz and then unzip the same.
2. Change in `/etc/profile` and set the JAVA_HOME as follows:

   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`
3. Then `source /etc/profile`

After this when I type `java -version` I got `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. When I type `which java` I got

```
/usr/bin/java
```

**Note:**

I had removed all `symlinks` of java and again created. Eg.

```
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin.java /usr/bin/java
```

and then

```
ln -s /usr/jdk1.8.0_151/bin.java /etc/alternatives/java
```

Post that I have tried

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java 1
```

Nothing happend!!! I still see that frustrating message when I check Java Version. `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`.

Can any body please share any light or thought on why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but you don't need to include `$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar` or `$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar` on the classpath.

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -version`?  (Or whatever the absolute path to the `java` executable is ...)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Does `java -verbose -version` yield more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good answer to this.  It sounds like the following bug report for Oracle Java SE 8u155:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194180

The tentative diagnosis from the Oracle engineer was that some dependencies were missing.  However, the reporter didn't provide more details and the bug report was closed as "unconfirmed".

My suggestions would be:

- Download and install a later release of Oracle Java 8.  (At the time of writing, the latest release was Java SE 8u221.)
- Go back to using OpenJDK from the CentOS repos.

For the record, Oracle do certify Java 8 for RHEL 7.x (which is equivalent to CentOS 7.x) but only for 64-bit JVMs.

Source:

- ["Oracle JDK 8 and JRE 8 Certified System Configurations"](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html)